# CocoaLibSpotify crashes the app immediately after Login. NSURL Extensions seem to be missing?

Tags: ios6, nsurl, cocoalibspotify-2.0

I'm building a new spottily app using cocoaLibSpotify.
Immediately after instantiating the session with initializeSharedSessionWithApplicationKey, I call attemptLoginWithUserName with a valid username/password pair.
The app then immediately crashes with

```
+[NSURL urlWithSpotifyLink:]: unrecognized selector sent to class 0x23e826c
2014-01-23 14:05:09.476 MercuryDockAssistant[44744:3f03] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '+[NSURL urlWithSpotifyLink:]: unrecognized selector sent to class 0x23e826c'
*** First throw call stack:
(0x22c2012 0x20e7e7e 0x234d2ad 0x22b1bbc 0x22b194e 0x44196 0x43d46 0x35aac 0x4398c 0x3305c 0x2e50d 0x2281920 0x2244d31 0x2268724 0x2267f44 0x2273f91 0x2e7d5 0xcd20d5 0xcd2034 0x2d0c5fb 0x2d0c485 0x2d11cf2)
libc++abi.dylib: terminate called throwing an exception
```

So it looks like the NSURL extensions are not being recognised. Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ensure you are importing the header wherever you are using spotify extensions like `urlWithSpotifyLink:`.

```
#import "CocoaLibSpotify.h"
```

Also, as mentioned in the [CocoaLibSpotify readme](https://github.com/spotify/cocoalibspotify/), you need to add the `-ObjC` and `-all_load` flags to the "Other Linker Flags" build setting in Xcode.

Comment: Thank you, adding the two build settings fixed the problem.